# Stack Overflow webpages are not displayed properly any more

Tags: support

My Opera browser has been unable to display Stack Overflow webpages properly since the other day. See the image. I don't know why. But there is no problem when it opens other webpages like Super User, Stack Exchange. Has anyone ever encountered such a problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the CSS is loaded correctly? Clear your browser cache and retry.

Comment: Bunch of workarounds are suggested in the dupe answers.